# Android - Google+ PlusOneButton click error

Tags: android, google-plus, google-plus-one

I am trying to include a PlusOneButton in an Android App. I have integrated the google-play-services SDK and enabled the Google+ API. The PlusOneButton works as expected in most instances, but there are occasional instances where I click the button and it returns the following error ("There was a temporary problem with your +1"). I can't find this error in the documentation. The button shows my profile, so it does not appear to be a sign in issue, but there appears to be some initialization failure.

Has anyone encountered this, or know of any solutions? Thanks!

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mPlusOneButton.initialize(<URL>, <GOOGLE_PLUS_ONE_BUTTON_REQUEST_CODE>);
}
```

[image: /Users/williammay/Desktop/Screen Shot 2014-06-10 at 10.40.26 AM.png]

Comment: Is the URL a working, public accessible web page?

Comment: Yes, the URL is the link to the app in the Google Play Store